# the use of replace confusion

Tags: python, pandas

I have the profit data, the type is:
Some example of the numbers are:

```
Profit            object
1168      -353.53
1169      -353.53
1170    -1 767.66
1171      -353.53
1172      -353.53
1173      -353.53
1174      -707.06
1175    -1 414.13
1176      -353.53
```

because there are some white space within the numbers:
If I use

```
orders['Profit'] = orders['Profit'].replace(" ", "")
then there is no change, after google, I turn the data into str first
```

I use:

```py
orders['Profit'] = orders['Profit'].str.replace(" ", "")
```

to get rid of the white space; however, the outcome is:

```
1168         NaN
1169         NaN
1170    -1767.66
1171         NaN
1172         NaN
1173         NaN
1174         NaN
1175    -1414.13
1176         NaN
```

Others may have the same problem,so I post it here, no idea why

Comment: what is the `dtype` of your `Profit` column?

Comment: Profit is object

Comment: you can use `orders['Profit'].apply(lambda x: float(''.join(x.split())))`, if all rows on your  `orders['Profit']` contains numbers only

Comment: thank you,but  AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: you may have  `Nan` in your column, if you are reading this data fram a css or an excel to pandas using `pd.read_csv/read_excel`, there is a parameter called `thousands` which denotes the Thousands separator in the data you can give `thousands =' '` as an argument in read_csv

Comment: brilliant, this is an easy way! thank you